# Delete and insert cells in a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a issue with the `indexPath` of cells in a `TableView`.

For example, I populate a `TableView` with a datasource of 5 objects [cell0 cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5]. For each cell, the `indexPath`seems to be good : the cell0 has the `indexPath` 0, the cell 1 has the `indexPath` 1, etc.

Then, I click on the cell0 in order to add a cell6 after the cell0 with the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` so now, my datasource is something like [cell0 cell6 cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5] and the `indexPath` of each cell seems to be good again : the cell0 has the `indexPath` 0, the cell 6 has the `indexPath` 1, he cell 1 has the `indexPath` 2, etc.

So, now, I would like to remove the cell6, and insert a cell7 after the cell2 to have the following array [cell0 cell1 cell2 cell7 cell3 cell4 cell5]. This action should occur when I click on the cell2. So, to do this, the `TableView` calls 2 methods : `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

So, when I click on the cell2, the method `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`is called with the `indexPath` 0. It seems to be good because the previous selected cell was the cell0. In this method, I remove the cell6 with the method `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. So now my datasource looks like the following array : [cell0 cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4 cell5] but the `indexPath` seems to be good : the cell0 has the `indexPath` 0, the cell1 has the `indexPath` 1, etc.

Finally, to add the cell7, the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`is called with the `indexPath` 3 instead of 2. So the consequence is that the new cell is not inserted at the good place... The dataSource look like [cell0 cell1 cell2 cell3 cell7 cell4 cell5] instead of [cell0 cell1 cell2 cell7 cell3 cell4 cell5].

Is there a way to force the refreshing of the `indexPath` ? Perhaps I do not use the good methods ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: hi @Staroun If you share relevant part of your code getting help would be easier and your question could get more attraction.

Comment: Please post the code, it takes care of most of the explanation :)

Comment: did that work for you? @staroun

Comment: I posted my code and captures.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what it is that you are asking but you can reload a particular indexPath with the following.

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPatshArray withAnimation:UITableViewAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question and approach does seem confusing to me.

I would recommend not tinkering and forcing the order in this way.

Update your data model but inserting the new data in your NSArray.
Something like this:

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"2", nil];
```

When user selects and makes changes, insert element in your array

```
[data insertObject:@"3" AtIndex:whatever];
```

At this time you want to reload your table view so from the right place call

```
[mytableview reloadData];
```

Same applies for your delete operations. Update data model and call reloadData. Let the tableview draw is based on what your cellForRowAtIndex method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.

First, I clicked on a cell to add a new cell. `IndexPath` is 0. (it's OK).
The method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called

Second, I clicked on a cell with a `IndexPath` 2.

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/777kuo88ra0v6jk/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%20du%20Simulateur%20iOS%2012%20ao%C3%BBt%202014%2009.30.23.png

The method `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is called with `IndexPath` 0 (it's OK).
After the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath' is called with`IndexPath` 2.

The new cell is added to the wrong `IndexPath`.

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/j02gjfx4bci4rs5/Capture%20d%E2%80%99%C3%A9cran%20du%20Simulateur%20iOS%2012%20ao%C3%BBt%202014%2009.30.30.png

When I clicked the `IndexPath` 2. the method `didselectRowAtIndexPath` changes te datasource (the cell "Test" is deleted). When the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. the `IndexPath` is always 2 but with the new datasource (changed by the method `didselectRowAtIndexPath`) `IndexPath` should be 1 to add the new cell below the good cell.

The indexPath is not update. Do I have to update myself ? or the tableView ?

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_dashboardDataSource removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 1];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section],
                                 nil];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailItemData *itemData = [[DetailItemData alloc] init];
    dropItemData.title = @"TEst";
    [_dashboardDataSource insertObject:itemData atIndex:indexPath.row + 1];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section],
                                 nil];


    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```